# Как правильно сохранить данные в связанные таблицы

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

Не могу разобраться с добавлением данных. Есть две сетки `datagridview`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и есть две таблицы со связями в базе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Cохраняю изменения так:

```
this.tableataptor.UpdateAll(this.dataset);
```

Так вот, при добавлении данных в первую таблицу и вторую одновременно выдаёт сообщение об ошибке, в котором ругается на связь между ними.
Если сохранить данные сначала в первую таблицу то данные сохраняются, и потом при выборе строки с первой сетке добавить данные во вторую сетку то они сохраняются.

Как правильно сохранить изменения в базу?

Comment: Nick Fast код показать можете.

Comment: Можете TabControl использовать для разных datagridview

Comment: Код insert update delete генерится на автомате при добавлении на форму. TabControl использовать не вариант, т.к. тогда во второй вкладке опять же будет две сетки, выбираешь строку в одной сетке и добавляешь данные в другую. Но опять же необходимо чтоб в первой сетке уже были данные

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка как раз в связи. У вас не успела обновиться первая таблица, а вы пытаетесь связанную с ней обновить вторую. Необходимо сначала в коде обновить одну таблицу, а потом вторую.

Comment: а как это сделать? если я делаю так: htis.registrtableadaptor.Update(dataset) а затем this.probatableadaptor.Update(dataset) то всё равно ошибка та же. По логике да я должен обновить первую таблицу регистраций а потом уже обновить вторую (дочернюю) таблицу